# Generate raster from factor-linked data in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a land classification raster with factor levels set (pixel val of 1 = 'type a', etc), plus a data frame holding the same factor in the first column, and then several columns of numeric attribute data.

I'd like to generate a new rasterBrick/rasterStack where that numeric data is mapped out - one map for each attribute. Not sure how to do this properly in R. I've tried

```
test <- merge(raster@data@attributes[[1]], data.frame, by = 'category')
```

but that gives me a single-band rasterLayer with multiple attributes (i.e. a RAT with more columns), which I can't then write to GTiff properly.

Comment: GTiff doesn't support RAT (does it?). Fwiw Kea was created for this reason, but you'll have to set up GDAL for it

Comment: This sounds like you want to reclassify the raster according to a table (vector) indexed by the factor levels.  That's native to `R`: see the help for `[`.

Comment: Any chance to have a small reproducible example of your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unfortunately KEA isn't an option on this project; it requires outputs in a more commonly used format. [ appears to be recommended only for small datasets, and mine certainly aren't! That also makes providing examples a bit problematic, but I'll see what I can do. I've had some success with deratify().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `deratify()` was the function I needed, just had to tweak the RAT a bit to make it all work.

After the merge, the RAT columns had to be rearranged so that ID was column 1 again. `deratify()` can then be run to produce a RasterBrick, each layer of which contains the data from one of the RAT columns (one can also specify a subset of those columns if necessary). The brick can then be written to a multiband TIF. Just a shame that band names can't be set, otherwise it works quite well.

I'd still be interested in seeing other solutions to reclassifying/recoding rasters based on an index. `reclassify()` with a two-column matrix produced nonsense results for me, and `subs()` just ate all my RAM and then crashed R.